# In solo play, am I the player to my right?

Tags: legendary-marvel

Last night I was playing [Legendary: A Marvel Deck Building Game](https://www.boardgamegeek.com/boardgame/129437/legendary-marvel-deck-building-game) using the standard solo rules. The villain group in my game was Underworld, from the [Dark City expansion](https://www.boardgamegeek.com/boardgameexpansion/137762/legendary-dark-city). On one of my turns, I flipped Blackheart who has three abilities:

1. **Ambush**: The player to your right (does something)*
2. **Fight**: Same effect.
3. **Escape**: Same effect.

Am I the player to my right? In other words, do I have to do the effect on this card if I am playing by myself?

- *I can't remember what this something is, but that's unimportant to the question.*

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Yes**, you are the player to your right (and left) when playing solo.

[From Devin Low](https://www.boardgamegeek.com/article/12967259#12967259), the designer of Legendary:

> Blackheart's effects say "The player on your right reveals a [MARVEL KNIGHTS] Hero or gains a Wound." When you do this effect in a two-player game, the other player is the player to your right, so that player must reveal or gain a Wound. In a solo game, the player to your right (going around the table) is yourself, so you gain a Wound.

Answer (score 0):

In the main rule book from the base set under solo play, any action that you would do to another player you do to yourself if playing solo.

Comment: Welcome to Board Games Stack Exchange. This answer would be even better if you included a direct quote from the rule book to support your answer.

Comment: I'm at work, and my rule book is at home. It is near the end of the book, the last 3 or 4 pages roughly.

Comment: Does this add anything that wasn't present in the other answer?

Comment: @JoeW I think it's nice to know that this rule is included in the rulebook.

Comment: @KingofNES I don't know if it's the right file, but I don't see it here: http://www.upperdeck.com/OP/RuleBooks/Legendary_Rules-Core_Set.pdf